# How do I let a jQuery.lightBox() be executed on a div that is hidden with one click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

Imagine the HTML is like this:

```
<a id="tour_gallery_link" href="#">Click Me</a>

<div id="tour_gallery">
    <a href="image1.png"><img src="image1.png"></a>
    <a href="image2.png"><img src="image2.png"></a>
    <a href="image3.png"><img src="image3.png"></a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#tour_gallery {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.debug("Page DOM ready");
    $('#tour_gallery_link').click(function() {
    console.debug("Clicked the tour gallery link.");
    $('#tour_gallery').css({
        visibility: 'visible'
    }).lightBox();
});
```

Basically what I want is when the user clicks the `#tour_gallery_link`, the `div#tour_gallery` will have it's CSS `visibility` changed to `visible`. Then `#tour_gallery a` will have the function `lightBox()` executed on it.

That's a very important distinction, the `lightBox()` has to be executed on the `a` links within the `div#tour_gallery` not just on the `#tour_gallery` itself.

However, the `div#tour_gallery` is what is hidden.

It would be nice if I could have the lightbox executed, while the div remains hidden - so once they press 'Click Me', it automatically jumps into the lightBox(), but I am not sure if that is possible.

I am using the jQuery.LightBox - http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Edit1: After I did the changes suggested by Calum, this is how the JSFiddle looks on my screen. It doesn't launch into the lightbox. It simply loads the `div` right below the Click Me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tour_gallery_link').click(function() {
    $("#tour_gallery a").lightbox({
        fitToScreen: true,
        imageClickClose: false
    }).parent().css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#tour_gallery a:first").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: This also stops once the div is visible. It doesn't execute `lightBox()` for whatever reason. I need to do two clicks.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is what i have: `$('#tour_gallery_link').click(function() {
  $('#tour_gallery').css('visibility', 'visible').find('a').lightBox();
 });`

Comment: Try the second statement above.

Comment: Tried it....nope...still just loads the hidden div and requires another click to load the lightbox.

Comment: Nah....that's what I am saying....mine does what the JSFiddle does. Which is, it shows the images (i.e. by making the div css visibility: visible). But your JsFiddle does NOT jump into the lightBox() immediately. All it does is changes the CSS from hidden to visible. I have attached a screenshot to the question of how it looks on my end.

Comment: Riiight, sorry I didn't understand the question fully. Here's the working one: http://jsfiddle.net/QUKVN/1/ Hope it's ok! I updated the answer above too :)

Comment: Great...now one more step. What I want to happen is, it keeps once I click the Click Me, I want it to just execute the lightBox() like it does now, but then keep the div visibility to hidden, so we can't see it. Can that be done ?